# Clojure; Design performant data structure for objects in 2D Space for collision detection

Tags: c++, performance, data-structures, clojurescript

I'm writing a game in clojurescript.

- It has a 2D game area for example from 0 to 10000 on the x and y axis.
- In this area there can be dots of different sizes.
- If the player touches a dot it will be deleted.
- There can be up to 2500 dots or even more.

Since the player can move every frame i would have to check all ~2500 dots 60 times per second.

If if where to be having this data structure:

```
(defonce state (atom {:food [{:center {:x 19 :y 51} :radius 1.78 :area 10}
                             {:center {:x 12 :y 34} :radius 1.78 :area 10}]}))
```

i imagine it to be quite slow and inefficient.

In C/C++ i would probably have created an array of 10000 by 10000 and used the indicies as x and y value/keys to a pointer to my object. This way i would only have to figure out how big the player currently is and which points of the play area his body covers. Then i would only have to check at those indicies.

```
dot dots[10000][10000];
// if player where a square of 5 at the moment at x=123 y=456
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
    isDot(dots[123+i][456+j]);
  }
}
```

Is there a similar way with clojure and it's data structures?

---

I tried to have a "point key" and tried to retrieve its value like this:

```
(def state (atom {:food { {:x 123 :y 456}{:radius 1.783 :area 9.9}
                          {:x 321 :y 654}{:radius 1.784 :area 10}}}))

(println (get-in @state [:food {:x 123 :y 456}]))
```

Is something like this possible? (This does only give me nil to print)

Comment: I created a spacial grid when I needed to speed up my collision detection. Implemented it in about a day; they're pretty simple. Of course the simple answer is use a library. Phaser is a pretty fantastic JS game engine.

Comment: Yes, with the answear and a spacial grid i will try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Three options for a lookup table

Your  *point key* is a map where each key is also a map, which does work. The `nil` that you see in your REPL is in fact what calling `println` returns as a result. The `(get-in @state [:food {:x 123 :y 456}])` part works fine; it returns the value associated with the key `{:x 123 :y 456}`.

I could think of three options for a lookup table in CLJS that are straight-forward to implement: a plain JS Array, nested ClojureScript vectors, and nested maps. The latter is a variant of your "point key", where first map is indexed by row number, and the inner nested map by column number (or vice versa).

Here's an example of initializing each of the three data structures:

```
; plain JS Array
(def js-array (reduce (fn [acc _] (do (.push acc (make-array 10000)) acc)) (array) (range 10000)))

; nested CLJS vectors
(def vec-array (->> false (repeat 10000) vec (repeat 10000) vec))

; nested CLJS map
(def map-grid (reduce #(assoc-in % [(rand-int 10000) (rand-int 10000)] {:radius 1.78 :area 10}) {} (range 2500)))
```

Note how the mutable state of the plain JS Array forces the code to be less idiomatic.

## Lookup performance measured

A quick-and-dirty performance test shows that the plain JS Array is (only) slightly more efficient for look ups than the other two. The following code shows performance testing with 100k lookups:

```
(defn exec-time [get-fn n]
  (do (time (reduce (fn [x y] (or x y)) ;; stop compiler from optimizing lookups away :-)
                    (repeatedly n get-fn)))
   nil)) ;; Suppress output

(exec-time #(aget js-array (rand-int 10000) (rand-int 10000))
           100000)

(exec-time #(-> (nth vec-array (rand-int 10000))
                (nth (rand-int 10000)))
           100000)

(exec-time #(get-in map-grid [(rand-int 10000) (rand-int 10000)])
           100000)
```

My results from repeating each series of 100k lookups 10 times in Figwheel REPL:

- plain JS Array: avg. 116, min 100, max 156 (msecs)
- nested vectors: avg. 141, min 128, max 194
- nested maps: avg. 246, min 232, max 305

The performance differences are so small that I would choose your lookup structure just based on convenience. In this case, I would prefer CLJS immutable structures (e.g., vectors) over plain JS. Note also that [the performance of cljs data structures compares very favourably to Immutable.js](https://github.com/swannodette/mori/wiki/Benchmarking). If you only perform something in the scale of 25 lookups per frame, then there is little lost in using the persistent data structures of Clojure(Script), and a lot to be gained.

Comment: Thank you! On my machine it's even faster.